# Action onchange for two dependent picklist in lightning:recordEditForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, dependent-picklist, lightning-recordeditform

I have two picklist fields, Country(controllling picklist) and State(dependent picklsit). State should change based on Country value for my lightning page.
 As of now this is  happening, but State field doesn't come on page when page gets load, it does when I make any change in Country Value. I want both the fields should be shown on page whenever page loads for first time and, also dependency should work.

Please find codes below -

**CMP CODE:**

```
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" access="public" />
    <aura:attribute name="refreshFag" type="boolean" access="public" default="false" />
    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters" style="margin-left:2px;">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordViewForm" recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                                  objectApiName="Opportunity">
                            <lightning:messages />
                            <td>
                                <label for="Country">Country</label>
                                <lightning:inputField aura:id="countyId" fieldName="Property_Country__c"
                                                      variant="label-hidden"
                                                      onchange="{!c.setStateRefresh}" />

                            </td>
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.refreshFag}"> 
                                <td>
                                    <label for=" State / Province ">State / Province</label>
                                    <lightning:inputField aura:id="stateId" fieldName="Property_State__c" 
                                                          variant="label-hidden"/>
                                </td>
                            </aura:if>
                        </lightning:recordEditForm>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div><br/>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
            setStateRefresh : function(component, event, helper) {  
        var refresh = component.set("v.refreshFag","true");
        //alert('v.refreshFag---->'+refresh);
    }
```

Comment: i dont quite understand what your question is, nor what your issue is. what do you mean by "I want both the fields Country and State altogether whenever page gets load"

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope it's understandable now.

Comment: if you remove your conditional rendering, both fields will display, i'm not sure why you have that condition, what is the purpose of the  refreshTag? Id doesnt seem to serve any purpose

Comment: Because dependency won't work otherwise. It will work first time when page executes, since it will take values from Record Page(back-end) , but if I change country, same won't reflect for State. Value for State remains as previous value, even we change value for Country because State field won't get refresh. I hope you get my point.

Comment: No, I don’t. Dependency does work with the recordeditform component out of the box, the controlling field will be editable at first, and the dependant picklist will be disabled until you select a value from the controlling field

Comment: You might be right, but this is not happening in my case.

Comment: remove your aura if's, the onchange event and share a screenshot of what is rendered, additionally, check in your console if you are getting any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency works with the recordeditform component out of the box, the controlling field will be editable at first, and the dependant picklist will be disabled until you select a value from the controlling field.

Your aura:if is not serving any purpose since your `setStateRefresh` methof is being triggered on page load.

I just setup some dep. picklists on opportunity to simulate what you are doing and the form is doing its job as intended:

[image]

it is also respecting the field dependencies I set:
[image]

Comment: Worked, thanks again! Can we put default value for Country picklist here, that doesn't match with record page value.

Comment: Not out of the box, you would have to code that